# FFMPEG cannot find H264 encoder

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running ffmpeg from a program, and we built ffmpeg ourselves (we did not install it with package managers or pre-built stuff).
This is the command that is built:

```
2020-07-31 12:14:11.942 INFO ffmpeg::FFTranscoder Executing: "../deps/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg" -y -r 26.062 -i ""/home/sstoenescu/Work/myproject/sample/myvideo.h264"" -c:v openh264 -vcodec h264 -movflags +faststart ""/home/sstoenescu/Work/myproject/sample/myvideo.mp4""
```

The file myvideo.h264 is valid, I can play it with ffplay and I can run ffprobe on it without problems.
However, the command above gives this error:

```
ffmpeg version N-98068-g16bdc2b541 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --arch=x86_64 --cpu=nehalem --disable-ffplay --enable-shared --enable-network --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-encoder=libx265 --disable-hwaccels --enable-hwaccel=h264_qsv --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi
  libavutil      56. 50.100 / 56. 50.100
  libavcodec     58. 90.100 / 58. 90.100
  libavformat    58. 44.100 / 58. 44.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 84.100 /  7. 84.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[h264 @ 0x5597c38defc0] error while decoding MB 86 45, bytestream -30
[h264 @ 0x5597c38defc0] concealing 2723 DC, 2723 AC, 2723 MV errors in I frame
Input #0, h264, from '/home/sstoenescu/Work/edvr/laba/gaoazar.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-c:v h264' will be used.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_v4l2m2m))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x5597c38e30c0] error while decoding MB 86 45, bytestream -30
[h264 @ 0x5597c38e30c0] concealing 2723 DC, 2723 AC, 2723 MV errors in I frame
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x5597c3905500] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x5597c3905500] can't configure encoder
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

It used to work, I did not change anything in the command, so I'm assuming it's something in the way we build ffmpeg. We are using these flags: `--enable-decoder=h264 --enable-encoder=h264_qsv    --enable-encoder=h264_vaapi --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264_qsv`
Here's the full configuration:

```
./configure \
    --arch=x86_64 --cpu=nehalem \
    --disable-ffplay --enable-shared \
    --enable-network \
    --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 \
    --enable-encoder=libx265\
    --disable-hwaccels --enable-hwaccel=h264_qsv --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
     #--enable-encoder=libopenh264 \
     --enable-encoder=h264_qsv \
        --enable-encoder=h264_vaapi --enable-encoder=mjpeg --enable-encoder=gif \
    --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264_qsv \
        #--enable-decoder=libopenh264 
    --enable-libx264 \
        --enable-decoder=png \
    --enable-protocol=tcp \
    --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-demuxer=h264 --enable-demuxer=image2 \
    --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-muxer=h264 --enable-muxer=image2 \
    --prefix="./build"\
    --disable-doc
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Comment: which one ffmpeg are you using - writingminds or any other?

Answer (score 2):

While reviewing this question, I think I fixed it. It's the most idiotic thing. The "#" signs, right after the "" in the ./configure command make everything after the first "#--enable-encoder=libopenh264 " not get taken into account. So all of the flags following that are ignored.

Comment: multi-line commands ends with \ cannot use with comment out # symbol